# <a> Con Href desactivado que funcione Angular

Tags: html, angular

En angular `href="#"` te manda a la misma página, pero quiero quitar el hipervínculo.

He probado con: `routerLink="['./']"` y  `routerLink="['./']"`

No hay manera. Cómo uso `href="#"`?

Comment: Intenta dar un paso más atrás para mirar con más perspectiva ¿Qué quieres hacer, realmente?

Comment: Si no quieres el href no uses un enlace, usa cualquier otra etiqueta, un span o un button van bien, aplica los estilos necesarios y ni quien se preocupe por el tipo de elemento.